# How to ignore asterisk characters in sqlmap?

Tags: sql-injection, cookies, sqlmap

I've come across a webpage that uses [Iron cookies](https://github.com/hapijs/iron). These cookies have the exemplary format: `Fe26.2**0cdd607945dd1dffb7da0b0bf5f1a7daa6218cbae14cac51dcbd91fb077aeb5b*aOZLCKLhCt0D5IU1qLTtYw*g0ilNDlQ3TsdFUqJCqAm9iL7Wa60H7eYcHL_5oP136TOJREkS3BzheDC1dlxz5oJ**05b8943049af490e913bbc3a2485bee2aaf7b823f4c41d0ff0b7c168371a3772*R8yscVdTBRMdsoVbdDiFmUL8zb-c3PQLGJn4Y8C-AqI`

Now, whenever I want to use sqlmap to test for SQL injections on that page (I have permission to test this page), sqlmap interprets these asterisks (e.g., ** and *) as injection markers and deletes them from the base request, resulting in a 401. e.g.,

`sqlmap -r sql-test.req --force-ssl`

```
[INFO] testing connection to the target URL
[TRAFFIC OUT] HTTP request [#1]:
POST /v1/data HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted
Cookie: auth_cookie=Fe26.275 [...]
```

As you can see, this should be `Fe26.2**75 [...]`

I could not find any option to ignore this asterisk interpretation.
Is this a bug with sqlmap or is there a clever way around this?

Comment: Url encode them or change them to a different chat and use a tamper script to put them back in after the request has been parsed for injection points

Comment: Different char, not chat